# Yii Validation: throw PHP error directly without Ajax warning text

Tags: php, yii

When trying to submit new Active record instance and save it to database table, I got direct PHP error message without AJAX warning text as I expect. It makes me really confused.
The PHP error message is:

```
mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

and it points to line 72 in ...Yii1.8\framework\validators\CStringValidator.php, Which is:

```
 $length=mb_strlen($value, $this->encoding ? $this->encoding : Yii::app()->charset);
```

And then, in next few lines, the PHP error continue pointing to this line in my AR Class (line 209):

```
205   $AttributesList = $saveArticleHistory->attributes;
206         $article_history->attributes = $AttributesList;
207         $article_history->article_id = $saveArticleHistory->id;
208         $article_history->id = null;         
209         return $article_history->save();
```

But my understanding is, if a AR instance failed to save to database, then a Ajax Warning is raised (if we cacht that Ajax error message in view). but here the warning message is displayed directly
? Could you help me with this confusion?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual value inside the mb_strlen?

Comment: It is an empty array. By the way, I can't understand why the error message is throw directly. If this validation test failed then Yii will display Ajax error text. But here it throw PHP error directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yii doesn't handle PHP errors, only exceptions so far. Here are some links related to this issue: [link1](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2857), [link2](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2155). For this particular case I think it's much better to check if `$value` is string before passing it to `mb_strlen`.